# Move Object around a platform of tiles in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, path-finding, tile

I want to make a spinning spike to move around a platform made out of tiles like in the following [image]

I have written every possible state on where to move when platform tiles block the spike's way. It would look something like this

```
     for (int i = 0; i < platformTileMap.Length; i++)
     {
         if (platformTileMap[i].HasTile(cellPosition + new Vector3Int(0, -1, 0))) // BOTTOM
         {
             moveX = moveDir;
         }
         else if (platformTileMap[i].HasTile(cellPosition + new Vector3Int(0, 1, 0))) // TOP
         {
             moveX = -moveDir;
         }
         else if (platformTileMap[i].HasTile(cellPosition + new Vector3Int(-1, -1, 0))) //BOT LEFT
         {
             if (moveDir == 1)
             {
                 moveY = -1;
             }
             else moveX = moveDir;
         }
         else if (platformTileMap[i].HasTile(cellPosition + new Vector3Int(1, 1, 0))) //TOP RIGHT
         {
             if (moveDir == 1)
             {
                 moveY = 1;
             }
             else moveX = -moveDir;
         }
         else if (platformTileMap[i].HasTile(cellPosition + new Vector3Int(1, -1, 0))) // BOT RIGHT
         {
             if (moveDir == 1)
             {
                 moveX = moveDir;
             }
             else
             {
                 moveY = -1;
             }
         }
         else if (platformTileMap[i].HasTile(cellPosition + new Vector3Int(-1, 1, 0))) // TOP LEFT
         {
             if (moveDir == -1)
             {
                 moveY = 1;
             }
             else
             {
                 moveX = -moveDir;
             }
         }
```

I feel like there has to be a more efficient way to solve this. Do I really have to write every possibility in if statements? Can I achieve this with pathfinding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

1. Use raycast

[image]

2. Place Empty GameObject and rotate spike when it arrives them

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of points to move to.

```
public Vector3[] movePoints;
```

You can set movePoints in inspector or in code (such as Start function) user choice

In the update loop lerp to the next point in sequence, when arrived pull the next point, unless we are at the end of the array then pull the first point in the array, rinse and repeat forever.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Set this up properly once, when you make more blades and different configurations or want to change speed it will be ez pz.

Comment: Is the intention with this is to save resources? So that it just calculates once at start and not constantly in every Update call.

Comment: it should save a little because its not doing as much if checks, but it makes your code more readable and extensible

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested. Here is how i solved it:

```
GridLayout platformGridLayout;
Grid platformGrid;
Tilemap[] platformTileMap;


[SerializeField] float rotationSpeed;
[SerializeField] float moveSpeed;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask platformLayerMask;

Vector3Int startPos;
Vector3Int currentCellPosition;

Vector3 raycastPlatformDir;
Vector3 raycastMoveDir;

float platformRaycastDist;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    movePoints = new List<Vector3Int>();
    platformGridLayout = transform.parent.GetComponentInParent<GridLayout>();
    platformGrid = transform.parent.GetComponentInParent<Grid>();

    startPos = platformGridLayout.WorldToCell(transform.position);
    Debug.Log("Cell Startposition: " + startPos);

    PlatformToMoveOn();

    GetStartRaycastDir();

    platformRaycastDist = platformGridLayout.cellSize.x;
    Debug.Log("CellCenterToWorld of Startposition: " + platformGrid.GetCellCenterWorld(startPos));
    Debug.Log(platformGrid.GetCellCenterLocal(currentCellPosition + Vector3Int.FloorToInt(raycastPlatformDir) + Vector3Int.FloorToInt(raycastMoveDir)));
}

private void PlatformToMoveOn()
{
    platformTileMap = new Tilemap[2];
    platformTileMap[0] = GameObject.Find("Platform").GetComponent<Tilemap>();
    platformTileMap[1] = GameObject.Find("MovingPlatform").GetComponent<Tilemap>();
}

private void GetStartRaycastDir()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < platformTileMap.Length; i++)
    {
        if (platformTileMap[i].HasTile(startPos + new Vector3Int(0, -1, 0))) // BOTTOM
        {
            raycastPlatformDir = Vector3.down;
        }
        else if (platformTileMap[i].HasTile(startPos + new Vector3Int(0, 1, 0))) // TOP
        {
            raycastPlatformDir = Vector3.up;
        }
        else if (platformTileMap[i].HasTile(startPos + new Vector3Int(1, 0, 0))) // RIGHT
        {
            raycastPlatformDir = Vector3.right;
        }
        else if (platformTileMap[i].HasTile(startPos + new Vector3Int(-1, 0, 0))) // LEFT
        {
            raycastPlatformDir = Vector3.left;
        }
    }
    raycastMoveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90) * raycastPlatformDir * Mathf.Sign(moveSpeed);
    //raycastMoveDir = new Vector3(raycastPlatformDir.y, raycastPlatformDir.x) * Mathf.Sign(moveSpeed);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    MoveSpike();
}

private void MoveSpike() 
{

    currentCellPosition = platformGridLayout.WorldToCell(transform.position); // + raycastPlatformDir * platformGridLayout.cellSize.y / 2;
    // Debug.Log(cellPosition);
    //Debug.Log(raycastMoveDir);
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, 300 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    RaycastHit2D raycastMove = Physics2D.Raycast(platformGrid.GetCellCenterLocal(currentCellPosition),raycastMoveDir,0.01f,platformLayerMask);
    RaycastHit2D raycastPlatform = Physics2D.Raycast(platformGrid.GetCellCenterLocal(currentCellPosition), raycastPlatformDir, platformRaycastDist, platformLayerMask);

    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, raycastMoveDir * 0.01f, Color.red);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, raycastPlatformDir * platformRaycastDist, Color.green);



    if (currentCellPosition != startPos) { // Check on Platform corners
        Debug.Log("Checking");
        if (raycastMove.collider != null)
        {
            // reassign raycastsdirections            
            RotateRaycastDirections(1);
            Debug.Log("Spike Collision");
        }
        else if (raycastPlatform.collider == null)
        {
            RotateRaycastDirections(-1);
            Debug.Log("Spike on Platform");
        }

        startPos = currentCellPosition;
    }
        /*transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
        platformGrid.GetCellCenterLocal(currentCellPosition + Vector3Int.FloorToInt(raycastPlatformDir) + Vector3Int.FloorToInt(raycastMoveDir)), moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); */

    transform.Translate(raycastMoveDir.x * Mathf.Abs(moveSpeed) * Time.deltaTime, raycastMoveDir.y * Mathf.Abs(moveSpeed) * Time.deltaTime, 0, Space.World);
}
private void RotateRaycastDirections(int angle)
{
    raycastPlatformDir = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90) * raycastPlatformDir * angle * Mathf.Sign(moveSpeed);
    raycastMoveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90) * raycastMoveDir * angle * Mathf.Sign(moveSpeed);



    // raycastPlatformDir = new Vector3(raycastPlatformDir.y, raycastPlatformDir.x) * angle;
    //raycastMoveDir = new Vector3(raycastMoveDir.y, raycastMoveDir.x) * -angle;
}
```

Edit:

This doesnt work on moving Platforms though. Any ideas how i could fix that? I tried changing the raycast position to the tilemapscentercell position but it doesnt work.